# Upload txt file and from first line take string for new file name

Tags: php, upload, rename

When upload .txt file on server I need to read it, take first line and this string from first line use for new file name (rename file).

For example I have file test.txt and in file have

```
First line - Username: DemoUser
```

I need to rename test.txt to DemoUser.txt and this DemoUser.txt to store in MySQL

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MCMXCII Not too much. I don't have good idea how can do it. I have upload script but need to take first line for rename.

Comment: Break it down, take it step by step. First write the part that allows you to upload the .txt file, then tackle reading that file, then splitting the lines out, then using the return of a line to create a new file. Have any problems along the way then come back here with some code that we can debug.

Comment: Once you read the file then you can get `DemoUser` via `explode( ': ', preg_split( '(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)', $uploaded_file_contents )[0] )[1]`. Good luck with the rest of it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my script

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
    $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
    $allowed_file_types = array('.doc','.docx','.rtf','.pdf', '.txt');

    $file = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"r");
    $result = fgets($file);
    $result = explode( ': ', preg_split( '(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)', $result )[0] )[1];
    fclose($file);

    if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 200000))
    {   
        // Rename file
        $newfilename = $result . $file_ext;
        if (file_exists("users/" . $newfilename))
        {
            // file already exists error
            echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
        }
        else
        {       
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "users/" . $newfilename);
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";     
        }
    }
    elseif (empty($file_basename))
    {   
        // file selection error
        echo "Please select a file to upload.";
    } 
    elseif ($filesize > 200000)
    {   
        // file size error
        echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large.";
    }
    else
    {
        // file type error
        echo "Only these file typs are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ',$allowed_file_types);
        unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: does the filename contain a path? eg, `/this/is/the/directory/file.txt`?

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji No, $newfilename only filename and extension. Before this I'm set what is folder. Here folder is users/